# How do I search a List<string[]> by the first column of the string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, search

If I have a list of string arrays (i.e. List), how can I search that list by the first column of the contained string arrays?

for example, say my list contains the following string arrays (assume the first column of each string array is the ID):

```
{"X7B", "col2", "col3"}
{"Y7B", "col2", "col3"}
{"Z6C", "col2", "col3"}
```

How can I find the string array in my list that has the ID of "Y7B"?

Comment: you should consider using a `Dictionary<string, string[]>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ:

```
var result = list.First(array => array[0] == "Y7B");
```

This will throw an exception if no matching array is found. You can also use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var result = list.FirstOrDefault(array => array[0] == "Y7B");
```

When no matching array is found `result` will be `null`.

If the logic of your code expects that there always is a matching array you should use `First`. Then, if the logic is violated an exception is thrown. On the other hand, if it is acceptable that there is no matching array you should use `FirstOrDefault` and handle the case where `null` is returned.

Comment: Could use `FirstOrDefault` to avoid the exception

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
var list = new List<String[]>();
list.Add( new String[] {"X7B", "col2", "col3"});
list.Add(new String[] { "Y7B", "col2", "col3" });
list.Add( new String[] {"Z6C", "col2", "col3"});

var found = list.Find(x => x.Length > 0 && x[0] == "X7B");
```

If there's nothing found, the result is `null`.

If you want to find all elements of the list matching the criteria, replace `Find()` with `FindAll`:

```
var found = list.FindAll(x => x.Length > 0 && x[0] == "X7B");
```

Comment: I think testing for zero-length string is useless.

Comment: That's testing for zero-length array. It's a list of arrays and the requirement is to check the first element which may not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ : this should work

```
var searchString = "Y7B";
var result = myListOfArrays.FirstOrDefault(x => x.First() == searchString);
```

result will be null if no result is found.

This method will work whenever the type of the elements in your array is : Array, List, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Linq extension method [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which was designed for this situation.

One simply defines a lamda which specifies the key to use as the lookup. Here we specify the first record of the list. We could *easily* do an other *compound* keys into it as well.

```
var data = new List<string[]> {
   {new [] {"X7B", "col2", "col3" }},
   {new [] {"Y7B", "col2", "col3" }},
   {new [] {"Z6C", "col2", "col3" }} };

  var lookup = data.ToLookup (key => key[0]);

  Console.WriteLine (lookup["Y7B"]); 
  /*
    returns string[] of Y7B, col2, col3
*/
```